# cannot link executable "node"- npm Error run in termux

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes, npm-start, termux

cannot link executable "node": cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node"...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem and just had to run `pkg update`
I hope this solved your problem :3